# How to get JQuery values from Node JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, forms

I have a form that contains JQuery widgets, a color-picker, and a slider. When users clicks on "validate", the form call Node JS.

I would like to know how I can get values of JQuery widgets from Node JS.
You can see somes codes below.
id="full" is just the Spectrum Color Picker.
id="amount" is a JQuery Slider.

Thanks for your help.

```
<form id="formulaire" action="http://localhost:3000/" method="post">
            <p>
                <label for="amount">Altitude 1:</label>
                <input type="text" id="amount" name="s1" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
                <div id="slider-range"></div>
                <input type="text" class="full" name="c1"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Tester" name="submit" class="button"/>      
</form>
```

And in Node JS (it's stupids lines, just to understand ! Here, the console.log doesn't print any values except for HTML input like basic text):

```
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function (req,res){                 

    console.log("Value : ", req.body.s1," Color ",req.body.c1);
}
```

Comment: Use events in widgets like slider and color picker to change values of hidden `<input>`s in your form then the values will submit along with other values

Comment: Can you write the code line ? I don't know what to do